# Не работают некоторые цвета в vim

Tags: vim, vimrc

Установил тему для vim: `joshdick/onedark.vim`
Тема нравится, но не работают некоторые цвета
Что странно, в `vimrc` все цвета работают, а когда редактирую обычный файл - нет, например, подсветки методов или функций

---

Как это исправить? Снизу скриншоты, обычные файлы на языке Golang и C, а также файл vimrc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не надо путать теплое с мягким. Цвета - это цвета, а синтаксис (в Виме) - это набор регулярных выражений. При чем для каждого языка - он свой.

Сделать полный синтаксис на регулярных выражениях для всех мыслимых языков да так, чтобы при этом ничего не тормозило и не тупило даже на самой древней машине - это утопия. Поэтому существующие файлы синтаксиса в Виме, мягко говоря, не полны. Проверить это элементарно: подводим курсор к интересующему месту и вводим команду: `:echo synID(line("."), col("."), 1)`. Если в ответ получили ноль, то, стало быть, никакой регекс здесь и рядом не валялся.

Что делать? Ну, можно взять и переписать все самому. Или найти готовый синтаксис, который сделал кто-нибудь другой, кому было не так лень. Или идти ставить Neovim с LSP, TreeSitter и прочими блэкджеками. Или ждать когда у Брама руки дойдут этот самый LSP к Vim'у прикрутить. Ну или, взять и прикрутить поддержку LSP в Vim самому и заслать Pull Request прямо на гитхаб. В общем куча возможностей ;-)